# What is the ejb-jar.xml equivalent of @Postconstruct?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-jar.xml

I have an MDB with a method annotated as `@Postconstruct`. It was being executed OK.

Today I needed to create an `ejb-jar.xml` file to configure an `<activation-config-property>` at build time (as I can't figure out how to configure an `@ActivationConfigProperty` at deploy time - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858781/changing-activation-config-of-topic-reading-mdb-at-deploy-time)).

After creating the `ejb-jar.xml` the container is no longer calling the `@Postconstruct` method.

What is the `ejb-jar.xml` equivalent of `@Postconstruct`?  EDIT: Or is it possible to merge annotations with XML config?

I am using WebSphere 7.

Comment: What server are you using?  Edit: oh wait, WAS 7, just noticed the other thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by ensuring that the `<ejb-name>` matched the MDB class name (sans package). With this in place the `@Postconstruct` method is found. See [this thread](http://forums.java.net/node/680771)